# Border flows over table but not paragraph with inline display

Tags: html, css

Using HTML and CSS.

I have text surrounded by a border using `display:inline` to make the border just larger than the text. The problem is that the border overlaps certain surrounding block-level elements. It overlaps `<table>` and `<form>`, but not `<p>`.

CSS:

```
.bordered {
  padding: 0.6em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  border-color:#E8E800;
  display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<div class="bordered">Some bordered text</div>
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<div class="bordered">Some bordered text</div>
<table><tr><td>Table text</td></tr></table>
```

Result:

[image]

Why is this? And why is it inconsistent between different block-level elements? I would expect that the table cell text be vertically aligned the same as the paragraph's.

**Follow up**: The whole reason why I have `display:inline` is so that the border is only as wide as the text. If using `display:block` (the default for `<p>`) then the border is as wide as the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The P tag isn't a vanilla block level element. Its default state in most user agents specifies some top and bottom margins.  The TABLE tag doesn't.  So the P tag is pushing the inline DIVs farther apart.

[margins on P tag http://homepage.mac.com/estranged/images/css01.png](http://homepage.mac.com/estranged/images/css01.png)

[margins on TABLE tag http://homepage.mac.com/estranged/images/css02.png](http://homepage.mac.com/estranged/images/css02.png)

Answer (score 0):

It *is* doing the block level elements the way you expect. None of the block-level elements are overlapping.

But the bordered text is not a block level element because you made it an inline box. If you put the bordered text inside the `<p>`, or inside it's own `<p>`, or get rid of the `display: inline`, then you will get a box-level layout as you expected.

*Update*: yet another way to fix this would be to put the stuff above the table inside a div (that isn't inline) and then style that div with identical but transparent margins and padding.

```
.blockMargin {
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: The rendered results looks exactly when the bordered text is inside a <p> (instead of a <div>).
Why is the overlapping different between a neighboring <p> and <table>?

Comment: The difference between having a `<p>` next to the `<table>` and a `div` that's class `bordered` is that the neighboring `<p>` is block level formatted and your `div` is inline formatted.