# Border minimally surrounding text using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I do this using CSS and HTML?

1. Bordered text surrounded by colored border
2. Bordered text's border minimally surrounds text
3. Bordered text has maximum width
4. Bordered text's border doesn't overlap neighboring elements

When rendered, it should look something like this:

[image]

For the border I'm using:

```
padding: 1.0em;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
background-color: #FFFFCC;
border-color:#E8E800;
```

If I apply the CSS to a `<p>`, then the border is as wide as the browser window. I want the border to only be as wide as the text (variable depending on the text size), so setting an absolute width using `width` doesn't work. I tried `display:inline` but that [causes spacing issues with neighboring elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370998). I also tried applying the above CSS to a `<span>` contained within a `<p>`, but that doesn't work when the text is too long and wraps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried experimenting with the CSS property called float?  Specifying float: left causes the width of the containing element to adjust to the text - seems like a secondary effect but it works.

If you don't want the containing elements lining up, <strike>you can add <br /> tags or</strike> you can add "clear: both;" to the style.

I definitely think it's achievable - you just need to find the right combination of attributes/values.

Comment: If you go this route, you can add clearfix to avoid extra markup. ( http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html )

Comment: Note: `<br />` tags won't keep the elements from lining up unless you apply some basic CSS to them: `br { clear: left; }`

Comment: I'll just scratch out the tag reference - the question is about css anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the highlighted paragraphs to minimally surround the text by making the highlighted paragraphs float left as block elements (`<p>` is by default). Then, get the paragraphs to `clear:left` to prevent them from stacking up horizontally.

The CSS:

```
.pars {
    /* this is used to prevent the last floating element 
    from causing issues below the paragraph (.pars) container */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.pars p {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
.pars .highlighted {
    float: left;
    padding: 1.0em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    border-color:#E8E800;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="pars">
   <p>Some paragraph text</p>
   <p class="highlighted">Some bordered text</p>
   <p class="highlighted">Some more bordered text</p>
   <p>Some very long bordered text blah blah blah 
   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
p.highlighted {
    float: left;
}

p {
    clear: both;
}
```

This will cause the highlighted paragraphs to only be as wide as required by their text, and will ensure that existing paragraphs never overlap horizontally with the highlighted ones.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a table to me... oh, I can see the comments and down votes coming already. "tables are only for tabular data"... Yeah, I know but they are also a qnd way of doing exactly what steve wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

what about display:inline-block?

Comment: IE6  / cross browser stuff about inline-block: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/